# Spark3.0 failed to write stream from cosmos changefeed to snowflake

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-cosmosdb

I use:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.cosmos.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to read stream from cosmos changefeed, but I run faild because of

```java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MetadataVersionUtil$
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
```

I found that MetadataVersionUtil is a new class in spark3.1, and I can't find a jar suitable for spark3.0, such as azure-cosmos-spark_3-0_2-12.
So I clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark.git and checkout 3.0 branch, and use `mvn install` to release the jar. But when I use this new jar, it failed because of:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: cosmos.oltp.changeFeed. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:195)
    at com.fti.cosmos.StreamToSnowflake$.main(StreamToSnowflake.scala:79)
    at com.fti.cosmos.StreamToSnowflake.main(StreamToSnowflake.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cosmos.oltp.changeFeed.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:663)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:663)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:663)
    ... 4 more
22/02/25 17:15:56 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

the scala code is:

```scala
val readConfig = Map(
      "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" -> s"${cosmosHost}:${cosmosPort}",
      "spark.cosmos.accountKey" -> cosmosPassword,
      "spark.cosmos.database" -> cosmosSourceDB,
      "spark.cosmos.container" -> cosmosSourceCollection,
      "spark.cosmos.read.partitioning.strategy" -> "Default",
      "spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled" -> "false",
      "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.startFrom" -> cosmosCfStartFrom,
      "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.mode" -> "Incremental"
    )

    // init spark
    val ss = SparkSession.builder
      .appName(s"${this.getClass.getName}-${cosmosSourceDB}-${cosmosSourceCollection}")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

  
    val df = ss.readStream.format("cosmos.oltp.changeFeed").options(readConfig).load()

    val sfOptions = Map(
      "sfURL" -> "",
      "sfUser" -> "",
      "sfRole" -> s"",
      "pem_private_key" -> "",
      "sfDatabase" -> s"",
      "sfSchema" -> sfSchema,
      "sfWarehouse" -> sfWarehouse
    )


    df.writeStream.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
      .foreachBatch((ds: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
        ds.toDF().show(false)
        ds.toDF().write
          .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
          .options(sfOptions)
          .option("dbtable", targetTable)
          .mode(SaveMode.Append)
          .save()
      })
      .option("checkpointLocation", f"wasbs://....")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

Has anyone successfully synced cosmos's changefeed with spark3.0, I don't want to upgrade HdInsight to 3.1 anymore.

Comment: The Spark connector is compatible with Spark 3.1, not Spark 3.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-spark#prerequisites. There is also a Spark 3.2 version https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.azure.cosmos.spark/azure-cosmos-spark_3-2_2-12

Comment: So there is no connector for spark3.0? I have to upgrade spark to 3.1?

Comment: Not that I can see in the documentation, no.